# Is it possible that Lua's libpcre implementation does not support '\d'?

Tags: regex, lua, pcre

I find that `\d` is not recognized as `[0-9]`. See my console output below:

```
> require "rex_pcre"
> return rex_pcre.new("[0-9]+"):exec("1234")
1       4       table: 0x2141ce0
> return rex_pcre.new("\d+"):exec("1234")
nil
```

Am I missing something or what?

**UPDATE**

As Kevin Ballard have correctly answered, string escaping works! e.g.

```
> return rex_pcre.new("\\d+"):exec("1234")
1       4       table: 0x21427f0
> return rex_pcre.new([[\d+]]):exec("1234")
1       4       table: 0x2142ee0
```

Thanks Kevin

Comment: I just did, it took sometime however, owe to the fact SO don't let accept an answer until 10 or 15 minutes have passed since the question was posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imagine it's because `\d` is being interpreted as a string escape by Lua. Try using `"\\d+"` or `[[\d+]]` instead.  The syntax is [explained here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1).